# What precautions should I take for burglars not to harm my dog

Tags: dogs

Last night, burglars got into my yard. My dog charged and barked and they run away. Friends tell me to be cautious because the burglars now know I have a dog and they might return prepared. 
I live alone and I work till 7:30 in the evening. During my working hours my dog is alone in the garden.
What precautions should I take to prevent burglars from harming my dog if they decide to come back during my working hours or during the night?

Comment: Get a bigger dog... Jokes aside, that could be added safety for you living on your own. Also, as keshlam stated in his answer below, there are houses without the complication of a dog around. Two dogs would make your house not worth it the trouble (hopefully).

Comment: Not cheap but a fence that is very difficult to scale and a locked gate.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting up some automatic flood lights. These will come on in the evening if someone is sneaking around. Thieves prefer the dark if possible and a light coming on makes them nervous, even if they don't think someone is home. A neighbor could see them and call the cops.

Also, if you don't have or can't afford a security system, then you can probably get some signs that say the property is under camera surveillance. I really don't think they'll be back, but these are two easy methods to help deter them besides your dog, who did the right thing. I think that's about as much protection as you can offer your dog, because even if he's inside, they're breaking in anyway and could do something to him.

Comment: I've already ordered a huge flood light system that will make the sun seem not bright enough..

Comment: If the dog is outside then he/she will activate the light.  Still good answer.  Just a comment.

Comment: @papakias That's great you already have a flood light. Like I was saying, it's not a preventative, just a deterent. And Paparazzi, you're right, but the sensor can be pointed away from the dog. Also, letting the neighbors know what's going on and they can keep an eye on your dog and your place. You do the same for them. It's just a bunch of little things that can help. Nothing, barring 24/7 armed security or you yourself being home and armed will completely prevent a burglary.

Comment: @Paparazzi Yes the floodlight will be installed to point to a non reachable by the dog entrance which is where the burglars came in from.

Comment: @papakias Cool but "My dog charged" led be to believe the dog could get to the burglars.  If the dog could not get to burglars then they would be just plain cruel to harm the dog.

Comment: No no, the burglars passed a second door after that and the dog coud get them

Answer (score 1):

They are unlikely to come back any time soon unless there is something about your house that makes you an especially attractive target. There are lots of houses without the complication of a dog

Comment: No there's nothing especially attracitve about my house.. I hope they won't come back...